# Passing Variables to procedure in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, hdl

I have the following simple procedure adding two numbers:

```
  procedure add_elements
  (
    x : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    y : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);   
    r : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  )
  is

  begin

   r := a + b;

  end;
```

I wanna make the use of this procedure in a process which looks as follows:

```
  test: process (....)
    variable inp1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable inp2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable res : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  begin

    ...
    inp1  := some_value_a;
    inp2  := some_value_b;
    add_elements(inp1, inp2, res);
    ...
  end
```

However, when trying to compile, Modelsim tells me
    No feasable entries for subprogram "add_elements"

Anyone an idea what went wrong here, is something wrong with the signature
of the add_elements procedure?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you are going to want a setup like this (I noticed a few typos).

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
```

I will throw in the obligatory note here that you might want to avoid using std_logic_unsigned and move to using numeric_std instead... Moving on...
Nothing interesting here:

```
entity top is
    port (
    clk : in std_logic;
    x : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    y : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
    );
end top;
```

In the architecture, we declare the procedure. I think you had a typo. (x and y vs a and b).

```
architecture top_arch of top is
 procedure add_elements
  (
    x : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    y : in  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);   
    r : out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  )
  is
  begin
   r := x + y;
  end;

begin
```

Now the actual process:

```
  test: process (clk)
    variable inp1 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable inp2 : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
    variable res : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  begin
    inp1  := x;
    inp2  := y;
    add_elements(inp1, inp2, res);
  end process;
end architecture top_arch;
```

And that's it. I think you were really close, just possibly missing a library and/or having some typos.

Edit: I should also mention that you *could* (and likely should) put the procedure in a separate package if you wanted for the purposes of re-use. Then you would need to include the package using the "use" statements.

Comment: definitely recommend using ieee.numeric_std.all

Comment: A suggestion to use a non-standard package, even with the warning note, isn't very good advice. Help us save VHDL :-)

Comment: I certainly recognized that using std_logic_unsigned is "improper" but in the interest of answering the question at hand most directly, I decided not to muddy the waters with a topic that the OP did not inquire about. The question at hand is regarding use of procedures.

Comment: The question seemed to be about procedures, but the problem really is about types, as can be seen from your answer.

Comment: Another thought: instead of using a procedure with just one output parameter, the natural solution would be to use function instead.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you need a procedure to add two numbers?  Why don't you just add them immediately?

**--Note that I make the assumption that the std_logic_vectors represent numbers.--**

I recommend to cast the std_logic_vectors to unsigned or signed first (`use ieee.numeric_std.all`) and use the "+" operator. You should never `use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all`, it will only give you problems.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the problem is with the signature of "+". In standard VHDL, there is no arithmetic defined with `std_logic_vector`.

As others have almost suggested, consider using `unsigned` or `signed` from `IEEE.numeric_std` instead.

For completeness, it seems that VHDL-2008 adds standard packages to do arithmetic on `std_logic_vector`. However, as with the non-standard packages, the numeric interpretation (signed or unsigned) depends on what package is used. I don't like that.